# WebView locale not picking up from phone

Tags: javascript, webview, locale, maui

I have my phone set to Spanish and I know the .net maui webview is reading it because when I alert the dialog is in Spanish but the navigation language is still English.  Can't figure out how to read the phones locale inside the webview javascript

Here is a screenshot from my phone:
[phone screenshot with phone set to spanish but javascript thinks its in english](https://i.stack.imgur.com/osgVc.png)

Comment: Do you want the webview's language to follow the phone's language?

Comment: Yes.  I have a WebGL web app running in a .NET MAUI WebView.  Please see screenshot above

Comment: BTW, I can't tell you how happy I am that .Net MAUI Webview supports WebGL.  Xamarin was great, but it's Webview did not seem to support WebGL (at least when I tried it).  This is going to be really great for Indie game developers!

Comment: Duh, I realize now that I was not looking close enough and the "US" part was making me think it was english.  I see now the es vs en

Comment: You can check if this webview supports multiple languages, if it supports multiple languages you can use js to interact with the system to get the system language to change the language of the webview, if the webview does not support multiple languages you will not be able to change it.